# Twitter Auth hanging after successfully doing the auth process with Firebase

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, twitter, firebase

I'm building a Chrome extension that uses Firebase's `AuthClient` to auth users with Twitter for my application. The problem I'm facing is that after the user gives their credentials in the usual Twitter pop up box, that box goes grey and doesn't close and doesn't relay the info back to my application.

Right now my application is failing it seems right before the `if error` line.

Here's some code from my `background page` (CoffeeScript):

```
base = new Firebase('https://silencerio.firebaseIO.com/')

authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(base, (error, user) ->
  if error
    console.log(error)
  else if user
    alert('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider)
  else
    # user is logged out
)

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (message, sender, sendResponse) ->
  if message.auth == true
    authClient.login('twitter', { rememberMe: true })
)
```

Any help would be huge. I'm so close to getting this working!

Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors thrown in the console for either window?

Comment: Also, I should note that FirebaseAuthClient has been renamed to FirebaseSimpleLogin: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html